# Error Woocommerce, no reconoce dirección de envío

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

estoy teniendo problemas con el checkout de una página wordpress que estoy realizando.
Primeramente el error que presentaba era de no reconocer la región, me pedía que introdujera alguna región de EE.UU a pesar de que en los ajustes la región elegida era Paraguay. Lo corregí colocando zonas de envío de Paraguay.

Pero ahora el inconveniente que aparece es *"Por favor introduce una dirección para continuar"* a pesar de que el campo de dirección esté completo. Alguna idea de que puede estar causando el inconveniente?

Tampoco estoy utilizando ningún plugin para alterar el checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Me pasó lo mismo, aunque en mi caso utilizo un plugin para agregar y modificar campos del Checkout y luego de innumerables cambios sin llegar a una solución, uno de los campos que habíamos deshabilitados porque no era necesario, era el de País (porque solo vendíamos en un solo país y no era necesario que el usuario lo seleccionara). El campo Pais deshabilitado en el checkout nos generó ese mensaje de error. Lo habilitamos nuevamente y el problema se solucionó. Espero te sirva!

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).